# Which is better to use "==" or "-eq" for comparing the integers in bash shell ?

Tags: bash, shell

I can see some article like  [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) where it is mentioned that "-eq" is used to compare the integers, but this doesn't say that we can't use "==" for comparing the integers.

I verified this on bash shell locally and "==" is working fine.
So can anyone let me help to understand which is better option to use, if "-eq" then why ?

Comment: Even for strings, `==` is not best practice inside `[ ]`; the POSIX sh standard specifies only `=`. Bash supports `==`, but this is an extension, and scripts using it may not be compatible with all other POSIX shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so is `==` a "bashism" ?

Answer (score 5):

To compare integers, use `-eq`.  The difference is that `==` compares string value while `-eq` compares numeric value.  Here is an example where they yield different results:

```
$ [ 03 = 3 ] ; echo $?
1
$ [ 03 -eq 3 ] ; echo $?
0
```

It is the same using `[[`:

```
$ [[ 03 == 3 ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ 03 -eq 3 ]] ; echo $?
0
```

As a number, `03` is equal to `3`.  But, as a string `03` and `3` are different.

**Summary:  To compare numeric values for equality, use `-eq`**

Comment: BTW -- I found it necessary to add my own answer for only a few reasons: Lack of mention of math contexts (in which case `==` is correct), and the implication that `==` is best practice in `[[ ]]` even for strings (whereas it leads to POSIX-incompliant habits when using `[ ]`).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. In a math context (which is preferable if you're writing your scripts specifically for bash), use `==`.

```
(( foo == 3 ))     ## foo = 3 would be an assignment here, and foo -eq 3 an error
```

A math context is also present in other situations -- for instance, indexing into a non-associative array, making `==` preferred but `-eq` illegal in the below contrieved example:

```
foo=( yes no )
bar=3
echo "${foo[bar == 3 ? 0 : 1]}" # echoes "yes"
```

---

In `[[ ]]`, use `-eq`.

```
[[ $foo -eq 3 ]]   ## $foo = 3 would be a string comparison here; $foo == 3 is a synonym,
                   ## but bad finger-memory to have if one wants to write POSIX code
                   ## elsewhere.
```

In `[ ]`, use `-eq` -- and also quote:

```
[ "$foo" -eq 3 ]   ## = would be a valid string comparison here; == would be a
                   ## POSIX-incompatible string comparison here; -eq is correct.
```